# Prevent knex database connection pool from closing when idle

Tags: node.js, database, connection-pooling, knex.js

I am using Knex.js to handle my connections to database. I am trying to prevent connection pool from destroying the connections that were idle.

My config looks like this

```
    {
      "client": "pg",
      "connection": {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : "15432",
        "user" : "postgres",
        "password" : "",
        "database" : "postgres",
        "charset" : "utf8"
      },
      "pool": {
        "min" : 1,
        "max": 7,
        "idleTimeoutMillis": Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
      },
      "migrations": {
        "directory": "app/database/migrations"
      }
    }
```

However I still keep getting

```
{"errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"read"}
```

After a period of inactivity.

To my knowledge, when enough time passes a connection should be thrown away from the pool. So if the connections are not used for a while (that is my case) there will be no connections in the pool and the first call I try should fail with given error. Subsequent calls go trough smoothly (until new timeout)

My question is - how to prevent this?

EDIT

after my app is idle for some time, first activity that has to go to the database level fails with given error. Any repeated call will be successful. That is why I came to believe that knex does not detect that a connection is being discarded as idle and it does not reconnect in time for the first query to be finished. I also believe that the problem is on the knex side and not on the database side.

Comment: Important detail is to tell where you get those errors. Knex cannot prevent database from closing connection, but if connection is in pool when that happens knex should recognize that connection was closed and discard it from pool. Also if you are using custom postgres db it might not signal correctly when connection is closed.

Comment: Aha, so you suggest that the problem might be on database side, i.e. the way the database was configured? And is there a way to tell knex to reconnect when a connection is discarded? @MikaelLepistö

Comment: When knex recognizes that connection was closed by server it sets `__knex_disposed_error` attribute (I might remember the name wrong) and that is used to validate if connection is fine. If that attribute is set, the connection is discarded from pool and new one is automatically created. So if knex doesn't recognize broken connection, then it might be left in pool causing problems every time that connection is tried to be used. There is no need to tell knex to reconnect, new connections are created automatically to replace old ones.

Comment: And you still have not added information to the question where from you are gotting those errors. It is perfectly fine to get errors like that for example from db drivers logs... but if you are getting those when you are making queries through knex, something is probably wrong.

Comment: I am getting this error when making queries trough knex of course... I would not tag it with knex.js tag if it was any way other... This is either tarn.js or knex.js or node-postgres issue. Like i said - I do not care about the downvote but having this answer posted here, would save me 20 hours of my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to fix

```
{"errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"read"}
```

errors, by making the configuration like this

```
{
  "client": "pg",
  "connection": {
    .
    .
    .      
  },
  "pool": { <- this is important
    "min" : 0 
  },
}
```

I found the suggested solution on 
https://gist.github.com/acgourley/9a11ffedd44c414fb4b8

Thing is, I did not manage to understand why is this a solution and why my previous configuration was not working.

Important thing to notice is that these solutions will **not** work

```
{
  "client": "pg",
  "connection": {
    .
    .
    .      
  },
  "pool": { 
    "min" : 0,
    "max" : 7 <- this fails in the same manner
  },
}
```

or

```
{
  "client": "pg",
  "connection": {
    .
    .
    .      
  },
  "pool": { 
    "min" : 0,
    "max" : 7 <- this fails in the same manner
    "ping": () => {... ping function ...}
  },
}
```

So to me this looks like circumventing some existing bug... The bug is either in knex or tarn.js or in node-postgres. Or, the issue might be that I fundamentally do not understand how JS database drivers work.

Comment: Sorry but I had to vote down since, this doesn't really fix anything. There is no reason why setting pool min: 0 without setting pool max would fix anything. Your link to the gist actually suggest fix to completely other pool, which is not even used in knex anymore. Also there is no attribute `ping: () => {}` ... the bug is most probably in your code.

Comment: Try to make simple reproduction code and in that way someone might be able to help you with this (or that way you may also actually proof that there is a bug involved here).

Comment: Mate... this works. And I am obviously not the first one to fix the similar issue like this. So it **does** fix my issue. I am very much aware that this pool is not used in knex anymore because I first blamed them for this issue, and talked to someone from tarn team. I do not use ping function in my code at all.  

If you want we could take this off this site, I could share my screen and you can see. I really don't care about the downvote but if some poor soul comes to this question this **will** solve their problem! This may be a hack, or there may be a better solution but **THIS WORKS**.

Comment: And about reproduction code... a simple knex.raw('select 1=1') will do... Like I said, if you are dev in knex team, or if have spare time to help mi with this I would share my screen and code...

Comment: Reproduction code, is a code that can be used for other people to reproduce the issue e.g. which database and version  you are using. Preferably all setup code with docker, since this sounds like very much depending on environment. There are hundreds if not thousands of people who are running knex like. `knex = require('knex')({client: 'pg', connection : 'postgres://<dconnectionurl>'})` and their queries work just file, so there must be something also wrong with your setup... and yes I'm dev in tarn and knex, thats why I know, that this is cannot be a real fix.

Comment: if `{min: 0}` helps it means that `{min:0, max:7}` should help the same way unless you have magic number 7 of bad luck (check created pool from `knex.client.pool`... min and max are always set).

Comment: it should mean that, it seams reasonable to assume that. However that is not the case. This sounds like a denial from your side, and I understand it perfectly. However I described the problem I am having and exactly what solved it. **These are the facts and this solution works.**

Comment: And about reproduction code. No, I have no intention to posting the full project here just to prove the point. I am accessing the db via database url, and accessing the db via knex.raw method. The fact is that db connection is discarded from the pool, and that knex fails to  re-establish the connection before next DB call is made. Why is that the case - I have no idea. Is the issue in the knex codebase, or is it someone else's fault I also have no idea. What I know for sure is that issue is not on my side, and as I said I can show that to you if you wish, as a proof.

Comment: Blaming the environment, or believing that I do not know what am doing will just prolong finding the solution and fixing the bug. And the bug is either in knex or the way pool is being managed.

Comment: From my point of view the problem is not properly isolating / finding root cause of the issue and randomly trying things found from internet. No one can help you to really fix this without reproduction... and no live debugging session with screen share is not the solution. Anyways I believe this comment thread is long enough warning already for people to not think that this actually helps, I just didn't want this issue to mislead anyone  :) ps. bolding doesnt make invalid statements true or change unproven thoughts to facts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192560/discussion-between-rouz-and-mikael-lepisto).

Comment: Using `{ pool: { min: 0 } }` worked for me as well. I'm using knex 0.21.12 with mariadb 10.3.28.